# Moved my time machine backup drive to another computer, can see it but won't recognise old backups

Tags: time-machine, backup

I've been using an external hard drive on my MacBook for time machine for a year or so. Now I have a Mac Mini too and have connected the external hard drive to that for the same purpose.

I want to leave it connected to my Mac Mini and still backup to it wirelessly from my laptop.

I have done all the steps to allow time machine to recognise network drives and I can see the drive from my laptop etc., but it won't recognise the old backups.

Do I need to change the file permissions or similar to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Just Just go into `System Preferences` … `Time Machine` and hit `Select Disk…`

(If that's not working, let us know what error you're getting/what does happen.)

Comment: More info at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/68766/33389